# Can my query be made more efficient, and how about adding a GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to write a query that returns:

1. The total amount of transactions that occurred before a date range, for a particular customer.
2. The total amount of transactions that occurred within a date range, for a particular customer.
3. The total amount of payments that occurred before a date range, for a particular customer.
4. The total amount of payments that occurred within a date range, for a particular customer.

To that end, I've come up with the following query.

```
declare @StartDate DATE = '2016-08-01'
declare @EndDate DATE = '2016-08-31'
declare @BillingCategory INT = 0

select c.Id, c.Name, c.StartingBalance,
(select coalesce(sum(Amount), 0) from Transactions t where t.CustomerId = c.Id and t.[Date] < @StartDate) xDebits,
(select coalesce(sum(Amount), 0) from Transactions t where t.CustomerId = c.Id and t.[Date] >= @StartDate and t.[Data] <= @EndDate) Debits,
(select coalesce(sum(Amount), 0) from Payments p where p.CustomerId = c.Id and p.[Date] < @StartDate) xCredits,
(select coalesce(sum(Amount), 0) from Payments p where p.CustomerId = c.Id and p.[Date] >= @StartDate and p.[Date] <= @EndDate) Credits
from customers c
where c.BillingCategory in (0,1,2,3,4,5)
```

This query seems to give the results I want. I used the subqueries because I couldn't seem to figure out how to accomplish the same thing using `JOIN`s. But I have a few questions.

1. Does this query retrieve the transaction and payment data for every single customer before filtering it according to my `WHERE` condition? If so, that seems like a big waste. Can that be improved?
2. I'd also like to add a `GROUP BY` to total each payment and transaction column by `BillingCategory`. But how can you add a `GROUP BY` clause here when the `SELECT`ed columns are limited to aggregate functions if they are not in the `GROUP BY` clause?

The `Transactions` and `Payments` tables both have foreign keys to the `Customers` table.

Sample data (not real)

Customers:

```
Id    Name    BillingCategory
----- ------- ---------------
1     'ABC'   0
2     'DEF'   1
3     'GHI'   0
```

Transactions:

```
Id    CustomerId Date         Amount
----- ---------- ------------ ------
1     2          '2016-08-01' 124.90
2     2          '2016-08-04' 37.23
3     1          '2016-08-27' 450.02
```

Payments:

```
Id    CustomerId Date         Amount
----- ---------- ------------ ------
1     1          '2016-09-01' 50.00
2     1          '2016-09-23' 75.00
3     2          '2016-09-01' 100.00
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help here. Why are you using subqueries here, are `Transactions` and `Payments` unrelated? Seems like you would be better off with `APPLY` and some conditional aggregation.

Comment: @Larnu: Because I want to get the totals for each subquery and couldn't see how to accomplish the same thing with `JOIN`s. I *am* currently getting the expected results. But I'm worried about the efficiency of the query, and can't see to see how I'd add a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Without knowing the data, this is hard (impossible) to give the "best" answer. Based on what we have, using `APPLY` and some conditional aggregates you could reduce the above to 1 scan per table (not 2 on `Payments` and `Transactions`) but I've no idea if you could use `GROUP BY` without a sample data set.

Comment: @Larnu: I'm having trouble understanding why. I thought the overall goal was fairly straight forward. I'm not sure how I'd even post all my schema and data from multiple tables here. The query above lists every column involved. I'm not understanding what information is needed that you could only get by seeing sample data? I have a `Customers`, `Transactions` and `Payments` table. The last two tables have foreign keys to the first. Both `Transactions` and `Payments` have `Date` and `Amount` columns.

Comment: Just sample data for the tables will be fine; but with out that we don't know the relationship of the data (are they many to one, many to many, one to one, or payments and transactions relate..?). The goal is clear yes, but the how to is not. It's like taking your car to the mechanic and telling them what the problem is, you're very concise on what that is but whe. They go to look inside you tell them they can't. They therefore think they know how to fix it, but without looking, they can't.

Comment: @As I mentioned in my last comment, the `Transactions` and `Payments` table both have a foreign key to the `Customers` table. So that would be a one-to-many relationship. I guess I assumed it would be obvious that a customer could have more than one transaction or payment, but perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: So payments and transactions aren't related? Again, a sample would simply answer any questions I or anyone else have.

Comment: There are no foreign keys between payments and transactions. Each have a foreign key to customers. They are related in that both are used to determine a customer's balance. But as you can see in my query, there is no connection between the two tables.

Comment: @Larnu: I'm honestly at a complete loss as to what information it provides that wasn't already provided, but I've made some fictitious sample data.

Comment: @JonathanWood . . . Your query is fine.  And with the right indexes, it might be just about the fastest way to do what you want.

Comment: To investigate performance, view the execution plan and see exactly what SQL Server is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build your sums seperately for `Transactions` and `Payments` in a CTE and then join them together:

```
WITH
    CustomerTransactions AS
        (
            SELECT CustomerId,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] < @StartDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * COALESCE(Amount, 0)) AS xDebits,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] >= @StartDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * COALESCE(Amount, 0)) AS Debits
                FROM Transactions
                GROUP BY CustomerId
        ),
    CustomerPayments AS,
        (
            SELECT CustomerId,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] < @StartDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * COALESCE(Amount, 0)) AS xCredits,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] >= @StartDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * COALESCE(Amount, 0)) AS Credits
                FROM Payments
                GROUP BY CustomerId
        )
SELECT C.Id, c.Name, c.StartingBalance,
        COALESCE(T.xDebits, 0) AS xDebits,
        COALESCE(T.Debits, 0) AS Debits,
        COALESCE(P.xCredits, 0) AS xCredits,
        COALESCE(P.Credits, 0) AS Credits
    FROM Custormers C
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerTransactions T ON T.CustomerId = C.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerPayments P ON P.CustomerId = C.Id
    WHERE C.BillingCategory IN(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with sub-queries to be more efficient.  Pre-query grouped by each customer for only those customers who qualify by the categories in question.  These sub-queries will always result in an at-most, 1 record per customer so you don't get a Cartesian result.  Get that for your debits and credits and re-join back to your master list of customers with a left-join in case one side or the other (debits/credits) may not exist.

```
declare @StartDate DATE = '2016-08-01'
declare @EndDate DATE = '2016-08-31'
declare @BillingCategory INT = 0

select
        c.ID,
        c.Name,
        c.StartingBalance,
        coalesce( AllDebits.xDebits, 0 ) DebitsPrior,
        coalesce( AllDebits.Debits, 0 ) Debits
        coalesce( AllCredits.xCredits, 0 ) CreditsPrior,
        coalesce( AllCredits.Credits, 0 ) Credits
    from 
        customers c
            LEFT JOIN 
            ( select t.CustomerID,
                    sum( case when t.[Date] < @StartDate then Amount else 0 end ) xDebits,
                    sum( case when t.[Date] >= @StartDate then Amount else 0 end ) Debits
                from
                    customers c1
                        JOIN Transactions t
                            on c1.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
                where
                    c1.BillingCategory in (0,1,2,3,4,5)
                group by
                    t.CustomerID ) AllDebits
                on c.CustomerID = AllDebits.CustomerID
            LEFT JOIN 
            ( select p.CustomerID,
                    sum( case when p.[Date] < @StartDate then Amount else 0 end ) xCredits,
                    sum( case when p.[Date] >= @StartDate then Amount else 0 end ) Credits
                from
                    customers c1
                        JOIN Payments p
                            on c1.CustomerID = p.CustomerID
                where
                    c1.BillingCategory in (0,1,2,3,4,5)
                group by
                    p.CustomerID ) AllCredits
                on c.CustomerID = AllCredits.CustomerID
    where
        c.BillingCategory in (0,1,2,3,4,5)
```

COMMENT ADDITION

With respect to Thomas's answer, yes they are close. My version also adds the join to the customer table for the specific billing category and here is why.  I don't know the size of your database, how many customers, how many transactions.  If you are dealing with a large amount that DOES have performance impact, Thomas's version is querying EVERY customer and EVERY transaction.  My version is only querying the qualified customers by the billing category criteria you limited.

Again, not knowing data size, if you are dealing with 100k records may be no noticeable performance. If you are dealing with 100k CUSTOMERS, could be a totally different story.

@JonathanWood, correct, but my version has each internal subquery inclusive of the cus